# import from node_modules from file in folder in same directory

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import

I have the following file structure:

```
-/
   - node_modules/
   - src/
     - App.tsx
```

Now from `App.tsx` I want to import from react with `import {View, Component} from "react-native"`.
This however doesnt work, but of course it does with the path `"../node_modules/react-native"`. How can I achieve to import from `react-native` in all files in `src` without having to write `"../node-modules/"` before everything I want to import from `react-native`?

Answer (score 0):

seems like my `node_modules` configuration was not correct, simply removing and reinstalling them solved the problem.